# Angular interval stay stuck

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to make a simple animation for quick pick to lotto line with $interval. 
The problem is that the interval never clear and i dont know why.

This is the important part of the code:

```
$scope.quickPick = function() {
    var count = 0;
    var lineAnimation = $interval(quickPickInterval, 200);
    function quickPickInterval() {
        $scope.clearLot();
        $scope.line.nums = _.sample(_.range(1, guessRange + 1), 5);
        _($scope.line.nums).forEach(function(num) {
            num = _.find($scope.cells, {
                num: num
            });

            num.isSelected = true;
        });

        ++counter;
        if(counter == 3) {          
            $interval.cancel(lineAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/vWGmSEpinf7wxRUnqyWq?p=preview

Comment: I think you need to change `counter` to `count` as you defined `var count = 0;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your code, `count`, no `counter`

```
//...
++count;
if(count == 3) {
//...
```

See fixed example, pls http://plnkr.co/edit/qeHmoNGQ3g3mW82c06OU?p=preview